# site-to-site VPN between cisco ASA and 870 cannot ping remote network

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

I have two sites which are connected through site-to-site vpn from cisco.
One site has a cisco ASA router, the other has a cisco 870 router

The tunnel has been setup, **and active**, however I cannot send any traffic over the link...

The ASA config is:

```
ASA Version 8.0(2) 
!
hostname ASA
enable password **** encrypted
names
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.16.10.5 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
passwd **** encrypted
boot system disk0:/asa802-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CEST 1
clock summer-time CEDT recurring last Sun Mar 2:00 last Sun Oct 3:00
object-group service RDP tcp
 port-object eq 3389
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.200.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 80 extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 
access-list 80 extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu inside 1500
mtu outside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
icmp permit any inside
asdm image disk0:/asdm-611.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
global (outside) 1 x.x.x.x-y.y.y.y netmask 255.0.0.0
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list 80
nat (inside) 1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 z.z.z.z 1
route outside 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0 a.a.a.a 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout uauth 0:05:00 absolute
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
http server enable
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set strong esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto map outside_map 1 match address outside_1_cryptomap
crypto map outside_map 1 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 1 set peer a.a.a.a
crypto map outside_map 1 set transform-set ESP-DES-SHA
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto isakmp enable inside
crypto isakmp enable outside
crypto isakmp policy 8
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime none
crypto isakmp policy 30
 authentication pre-share
 encryption des
 hash sha
 group 1
 lifetime 86400
no crypto isakmp nat-traversal
telnet 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
telnet timeout 5
ssh 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
console timeout 0
dhcpd auto_config outside
!

threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect pptp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
tunnel-group a.a.a.a type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group a.a.a.a ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
prompt hostname context 
Cryptochecksum:f9c4dfffca26f9975d64ad42a3a71452
: end
asdm image disk0:/asdm-611.bin
no asdm history enable
```

The 870 config is:

```
Current configuration : 3749 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no logging buffered
enable secret 5 ****
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authorization exec default local 
!
!
aaa session-id common

dot11 syslog
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
username Administrator view root secret 5 ****
! 
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr 3des
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
!
crypto isakmp policy 2
 authentication pre-share
crypto isakmp key * address x.x.x.x
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA1 esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ASA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
!
crypto map SDM_CMAP_1 1 ipsec-isakmp 
 description Tunnel tox.x.x.x
 set peer x.x.x.x
 set transform-set ASA 
 match address 102
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
!
controller DSL 0
 line-term cpe
!
!
!
!
interface BRI0
 no ip address
 encapsulation hdlc
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0
!
interface FastEthernet1
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface FastEthernet2
!
interface FastEthernet3
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 172.16.20.6 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 ip address a.a.a.a 255.255.192.0
 crypto map SDM_CMAP_1
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 b.b.b.b
!
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
access-list 102 remark CCP_ACL Category=4
access-list 102 remark IPSec Rule
access-list 102 permit ip 172.16.20.0 0.0.0.255 172.16.10.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 transport input ssh
 transport output ssh
!
scheduler max-task-time 5000
end
```

Where a.a.a.a is the external ip of the 870 router, x.x.x.x is the external ip of the ASA router. Some parts are left away, and passwords are blanked out.

Pinging from any host in either network to any host in the other network doesn't work. Neither do RDP sessions, SSH sessions, ... (So it's not just ICMP)

Comment: can you post the out put from the following command: show crypto isakmp sa

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following from your ASA

```
route outside 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0 a.a.a.a 1
```

By having this route statement in place the ASA will not be able to send or return traffic through the tunnel.

Additionally, you define your "to protect/interesting" traffic in the following ACL which is referenced in your crypto map.

```
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0
```

Your nat exemption/identity is interesting when looking at the crypto map match ACL above.

```
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 172.16.200.0 255.255.255.0
access-list 80 extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 
access-list 80 extended permit ip 172.16.10.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.20.0 255.255.255.0 
nat (inside) 0 access-list 80
```

Your access-list 80 has redundant matches in it.  Line 1 of the ACL, when the object-group is expanded -- will match line 2 of the ACL.  Redundant and should probably be fixed, but not likely the cause of any problems here.